# Relations between eigenvalues and determinant of an integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$.
>
> (1) Prove that if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $k$ divides $\det A$.
>
> (2) Let $j \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the sum of all entries in each line of $A$ is equal to $j$. Prove that $j$ divides $\det A$.

**Attempt.**

(1) Let

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{array}\right).$$

We can write

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha_1 & \cdots & \times\\
0 & \alpha_2 & \times\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & \alpha_n
\end{array}\right).$$

Thus, $\det A = \alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_n$. If $k$ is an eigenvalue, so $k$ is a root of $\det(A - xI) = \pm(\alpha_1 - x)\cdots(\alpha_n - x)$. Therefore, $k = \alpha_i$ for some $\alpha_i$.

(2) Let

$$A^T = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{array}\right).$$

Note that

$$A^T e_i = (a_{1i},a_{2i},...,a_{ni})^T.$$

So,
$$A^T h = A^T (e_1 + \cdots + e_n) = (a_{11},a_{21},...,a_{n1})^T + (a_{1n},a_{2n},...,a_{nn})^T = (a_{11} + \cdots + a_{1n},...,a_{n1} + ... + a_{nn})^T = j(1,...,1)^T = j(e_1 + \cdots + e_n) = jh.$$

Therefore, $j$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$. Since $A$ and $A^T$ has the same eigenvalues, the result follows by the previous item.

---

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof for part (2) is great!

Your proof for part (1) is incorrect; in particular, note that if your proof were correct, then it would also apply to matrices that do not have integer entries.  Note that
$$
A = \pmatrix{k&0\\0&1/k}
$$
has $k$ as an eigenvalue, but has determinant $1$, which is not divisible by $k$ (for an integer $k \geq 2$).
I think that that the simplest approach is to apply the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo $k$ we have $\ \det A \equiv \det(A-k I_n)=0$